# Vue3 Vite: How to manage to get 2 different commands to run the app from different vite.config.ts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I had an app based on Vue2 and I making the same on Vue3.
On the Vue2 app I could start "yarn serve" or "yarn serve:customers" to run the "admin app" or the "Customers App" in dev mode.

That was made with package.json :

```
scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build:customers": "vue-cli-service build src/apps/customers-app/main.js",
    "serve:customers": "vue-cli-service serve src/apps/customers-app/main.js" 
}
```

So I had the main app (admin) in the root of the "src" folder, and had an "apps/customers-app" in "src" for the Customers app.

Inside I had another main.js, router.js etc.
But one single vue.config.js

On the new app (Vue3), I try to achieve the same but I couldn't make it.

What I've done:

in customers-app I got:

- index.html
- main.ts
- router.ts

In this index.html I load the main.ts from this same customers-app folder.
In the other index.html (from the root) I load the main.ts from the root (admin)

I have also 2 vite.configs in the root:

- vite.config.ts (admin)
- vite.congig.customers.ts (customer)

What changes inside is that:

```
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        input: {
            main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            customers: resolve(__dirname, 'customers.html'),
        },
    },
}
```

this is when I start the build command its makes 2 differents html for the 2 differents app (that's ok)

in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "build": "vite build",
    "build:customers": "vite build --config vite.config.customers.ts",
    "serve:customers": "vite --config vite.config.customers.ts",
    "dev:customers": "vite --config vite.config.customers.ts",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "format:check": "prettier --check ."
  },
```

But to start the DEV server I have a problem, is I start with customers app (npm run dev:customers), the app starts well BUT I have to go to "http://localhost:8080/customers.html" but not "http://localhost:8080/".

So this is a problem for Vue-router, It can't work like that.

I just would like to use "http://localhost:8080/" all the time on whatever app I start